# Writing Form Data To SQLLite Database

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write my data from my forms data and I'm getting the following error. FYI: Total noob on python and django.

AttributeError at /forms/
'NewStudentForm' object has no attribute 'save'

From reading online its because I'm doing in my forms.py is (forms.Forms) and it doesn't use the .save() attribute.

What is the easiest way to fix this ? Thank you!

```py
#forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import StudentCheck

class NewStudentForm(forms.Form):
    startdate = forms.DateField(label = "Start Date", required= True)  
    esy = forms.BooleanField(label = "ESY", required= False)
    ten_month_school_year = forms.BooleanField(label= "Ten Month School Year", required= False)
    other = forms.BooleanField(required= False)
    intakedate = forms.DateField(label = "Intake Date", required= True)
    grade = forms.CharField(label= "Grade",max_length=2)
    firstname = forms.CharField(label = "First Name", max_length=50)
    lastname = forms.CharField(label = "Last Name", max_length=60)
    address = forms.CharField(label = "Address", max_length=100)
    city = forms.CharField(label = "City", max_length=100)
    state = forms.CharField(label = "State", max_length=30)
    zipcode = forms.CharField(label = "Zip Code",max_length=5)
    parent_one_name = forms.CharField(label = "Parent 1",max_length=100)
    parent_one_phone = forms.CharField(label = "Phone",max_length=12)
    parent_one_email = forms.CharField(label = "Email",max_length=100)
    parent_two_name = forms.CharField(label= "Parent 2",max_length=100)
    parent_two_phone = forms.CharField(label= "Phone",max_length=12)
    parent_two_email = forms.CharField(label = "Email", max_length=100)
```

```py
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class StudentCheck (models.Model):
    startdate = models.DateField(max_length= 10)  
    esy = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    ten_month_school_year = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    other = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    intakedate = models.DateField(default = False,max_length=10)
    grade = models.CharField(default = False,max_length=2)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    firstname = models.CharField(default = False,max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(default = False,max_length=60)
    address = models.CharField(default = False,max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(default = False,max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(default = False,max_length=30)
    zipcode = models.CharField(default = False, max_length=5)
    parent_one_name = models.CharField(default = False, max_length= 100)
    parent_one_phone = models.CharField(default = False,max_length=100)
    parent_one_email = models.CharField(default =False,max_length=100)
    parent_two_name = models.CharField(default = False, max_length=100)
    parent_two_phone = models.CharField(default = False, max_length=12)
    parent_two_email = models.CharField(default = False, max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname
```

```py
#views.py
from .models import StudentCheck
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from forms.forms import NewStudentForm
from django.urls import reverse






# Create your views here.


def NewStudentFormCheckList (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewStudentForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()


    else:
        form = NewStudentForm()    

    return render(request, 'forms/newstudentcheck_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/). And your form should look something like this:

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import StudentCheck

class NewStudentForm(forms.Form):
   class Meta:
      model = StudentCheck
      fields = __all__
```